# borrowed value does not live long enough when write an generic object mapping function in rust

Tags: rust

I want to mapping object using this code snippnet in rust:

```
fn map_entity_vec<T: 'static,E>(sources:Vec<T>) -> Vec<E> where E: From<&'static T>, E: Clone {
    if sources.is_empty() {
        return Vec::new();
    }
    let mut responses= Vec::new();
    for source in sources {
        let template_response = E::from(&source);
        responses.push(template_response.clone());
    }
    return responses;
}
```

the compiler shows eror:

```
error[E0597]: `source` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:41
   |
13 |         let template_response = E::from(&source);
   |                                 --------^^^^^^^-
   |                                 |       |
   |                                 |       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                 argument requires that `source` is borrowed for `'static`
14 |         responses.push(template_response.clone());
15 |     }
   |     - `source` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

what should I do to avoid this problem? I have tried to remove the lifetime static but the compiler tell me it should be added. I am still not figure out what should I do to make the object mapping function work.

Comment: What error do you get if you remove `'static`? `'static` is definitely not what you want to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Higher Rank Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) here to satisfy the compiler, not make everything `'static`:

```rust
fn map_entity_vec<T, E>(sources: Vec<T>) -> Vec<E>
where
    for<'a> E: From<&'a T>,
    E: Clone,
{
    if sources.is_empty() {
        return Vec::new();
    }
    let mut responses = Vec::new();
    for source in sources {
        let template_response = E::from(&source);
        responses.push(template_response.clone());
    }
    return responses;
}
```

This can also be simplified using the iterator functions to:

```rust
fn map_entity_vec_2<T, E>(sources: Vec<T>) -> Vec<E>
where
    for<'a> E: From<&'a T> + Clone,
{
    sources.iter().map(E::from).collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ac0a769d0362fe02774395d27954928)

Edit: You also don't need `E: Clone` since `E::from` returns `E` not `&E`:

```rust
fn map_entity_vec_3<T, E>(sources: Vec<T>) -> Vec<E>
where
    for<'a> E: From<&'a T>,
{
    sources.iter().map(E::from).collect()
}
```

Comment: Since the function takes ownership of the `sources` vector (which is dropped at the end), one wonders whether `into_iter()` shouldn't be used here instead, especially if `T` and `E` have the same layout, as Rust would then perform the operation in-place on the existing `Vec` allocation (its `FromIterator` implementation is specialised for that case).